# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis-7

I am finding various google results, but none seem to fix my problem. Below is the explanation.

When I have moved the website from staging to production while running it is giving me this error:

[image]

Where am missing to create, do I need to create anything to avoid the error?

Comment: Did the trick, If we use windows authentication it will not workout, will have to use sql authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you plase IIS on first server, and a database on second. If two servers work in intranet, you can connect to SQL server on second server by Windows integrity authentication.
Check connection string, if it contains:

```
Data Source=SERVER_NAME;Initial Catalog=DB_NAME;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

And add in Web.config file:

```
<system.web>
  <identity impersonate="true" />
</system.web>
```

[How to: Access SQL Server Using Windows Integrated Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx)

Or you can change connection from integrated security to user credentials:

```
Data Source=SERVER_NAME;Initial Catalog=DB_NAME;Integrated Security=False;User Id=USER_ID;Password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

[SQL Server Connection Strings for ASP.NET Web Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I hope that this might help someone. I had exactly the same issue and not of the solutions seems to work for me. A little background is that I has updated my window server r2 server to also host a dotnet core application. This is the point when I started getting this error. The fix after agonizing for a few hours was to simply change the server name in my web.config file from **127.0.0.1** to **localhost**. I really don't know why this worked but I hope this helps someone.